# Read a CSV with , inside the double quotes and extra quotes

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

I have a CSV file looking like this:

```
"Name1", "A test, which "fails" all the time"
"Name2", "A test, which "fails" all the time"
"Name3", "A test, which "fails" all the time"
```

My code is:

```
Using parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(filepath)
        parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = False
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not parser.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = parser.ReadFields()

            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            Finally

            End Try

        End While
    End Using
```

The error that I get is Line 1 cannot be passed using the current Delimiters. is not valid and will be skipped.
At first, I thought that the comma was the problem but it looks like the problem are the quotes inside the quotes

Any ideas how to read it?

PS. The files that my code face usually they don't have quotes inside the quotes, so I am looking for a fast, reliable, generic way to read the files.
Regex is, from what I read, very heavy for my purpose.

Comment: Could the files be re-written with the double-quotes correctly written as `""`? Is the item with the double-quotes always the last item on a line? Do any of the other fields have commas in them?

Comment: The file contains invalid csv. Can you fix that mess or do you have to parse it?

Comment: Can you change the 'CSV' file so that the delimiter is a semi-colon, pipe or some other character that will not appear in the other 'fields'

Comment: I don't see any problem reading this CSV. You only have 2  fields. Is the file always have this format Name (with no comma) and the second field? You also said the file doesn't contain quotes inside quotes. Why did you post with quote on this inside? "Name3", "A test, which fails all the time"

Comment: @AndrewMorton No because the code runs automatically. The files are random. I have no idea what I am expecting, but usually they are normal CSV files, expect this one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter No I can't I have to parse it.

Comment: @Chillzy THis is just an example. I am saying that in general, this is not the format that I get, but just one occasion, and that is why I need a generic solution

Comment: @Mych Imagine that I am parsing 100-200 files each day (which all are normals except 1 or 2). If I do this for every file the timing cost will be huge.

Comment: @Nianios: OK, i have provided a method below. Have a look. Note that it's not really tested and won't work for every edge case

Answer (score 0):

This file contains invalid CSV and normally cannot be parsed. So you should fix the source of the "mess". However, if you can't do that you could write a method which tries to fix it:

```
Function FixRowFieldsQuoteIssue(parser As TextFieldParser) As String()
    If Not parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes Then Return Nothing 'method fixes quote issue

    Dim errorLine As String = parser.ErrorLine
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorLine) Then Return Nothing ' empty line no quote issue

    errorLine = errorLine.Trim()
    If Not errorLine.StartsWith("""") Then Return Nothing ' must start with quote otherwise fix not supported

    Dim lineFields As New List(Of String)
    Dim insideField As Boolean = False
    Dim currentField As New List(Of Char)

    For i As Int32 = 0 To errorLine.Length - 1
        Dim c As Char = errorLine(i)
        Dim isDelimiter = parser.Delimiters.Contains(c)
        Dim isQuote = c = """"

        If insideField Then
            If isQuote Then
                If i = errorLine.Length - 1 OrElse 
                    parser.Delimiters.Contains(errorLine(i + 1)) Then
                    ' delimiter follows, this is a valid end field quote
                    ' can be improved by skipping spaces until delimiter
                    insideField = False
                    lineFields.Add(String.Concat(currentField))
                    currentField = New List(Of Char)
                Else
                    ' next char not a delimiter, this is invalid
                    ' add this quote to regular field-chars to fix it
                    currentField.Add(c)
                End If
            Else
                ' regular char, add it to the current field chars
                currentField.Add(c)
            End If
        ElseIf isQuote Then
            insideField = True
        End If
    Next

    Return lineFields.ToArray()
End Function
```

Call it from  the `Catch`:

```
Dim allRowFields As New List(Of String())

Using parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("filePath")
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = False

    While Not parser.EndOfData
        Try
            Dim currentRowFields As String() = parser.ReadFields()
            allRowFields.Add(currentRowFields)
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            Dim fixedFields As String() = FixRowFieldsQuoteIssue(parser)
            If fixedFields IsNot Nothing Then
                allRowFields.Add(fixedFields)
            Else
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "Is Not valid And will be skipped.")
            End If
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll test it and let it know

Answer (score 0):

Since the CSV data is formatted incorrectly, you'll need to parse the data manually. Luckily since you only have two fields and the first field doesn't contain the invalid format, you can do this by simply get the index of the first instance of a comma and separating the fields like that.

Here is a quick example:

```
Private Function Parse_CSV(ByVal csv As String) As DataTable
  'Create a new instance of a DataTable and create the two columns
  Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("CSV")
  dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Column1"), New DataColumn("Column2")})

  'Placeholder variable for the separator
  Dim separator As Integer = -1

  'Iterate through each line in the data
  For Each line As String In csv.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    'Get the first instance of a comma
    separator = line.IndexOf(","c)

    'Check to make sure the data has two fields
    If separator = -1 Then
      Throw New MissingFieldException("The current line is missing a separator: " & line)
    ElseIf separator = line.Length - 1 Then
      Throw New MissingFieldException("The separator cannot appear at the end of the line, this is occuring at: " & line)
    Else
      'Add the two fields to the datatable(getting rid of the starting and ending quotes)
      dt.Rows.Add({line.Substring(0, separator), line.Substring(separator + 2)})
    End If
  Next

  'Return the data
  Return dt
End Function
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ezSO1g)

Comment: This file is just a demo. The actual file is much much bigger with 120 columns. Also this is just one file of many that I have to parse that are different

Answer (score 0):

This will split your CSV into 2 columns and leave your quotes on the inside.
replace xline by 1 line of your CSV

```
Dim xdata As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
Dim xline As String = """Name3"", ""A test, which ""fails"" all the time"""
Dim FirstCol As Integer = Strings.InStr(xline, ",")
xdata.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(Strings.Left(xline, FirstCol - 1).Replace(Chr(34), ""), Strings.Mid(xline, FirstCol + 2).Remove(0, 1).Remove(Strings.Mid(xline, FirstCol + 2).Remove(0, 1).Length - 1, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library to read and write CSV files.

Couple of ways you can parse your files

Method 1: Specify the column names

```
using (var parser = new ChoCSVReader("NestedQuotes.csv")
    .WithFields("name", "desc")
    )
{
    foreach (dynamic x in parser)
        Console.WriteLine(x.name + "-" + x.desc);
}
```

Method 2: Access by index (no column names to be specified)

```
using (var parser = new ChoCSVReader("NestedQuotes.csv"))
{
    foreach (dynamic x in parser)
        Console.WriteLine(x[0] + "-" + x[1]);
}
```

Hope it helps.

For more help on, please read the below codeproject article.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1145337/Cinchoo-ETL-CSV-Reader